# Am I using PCA in Orange in a correct way?

Tags: orange

I am analysing if 15 books can be grouped according to 6 variables (of the 15 books, 2 are written by an author, 6 by an other one, and 7 by an other one). I counted the number of occurrences of the variables and I calculated the percentage. Then I used Orange software to use PCA. I uploaded the file. selected the columns and rows. And when it comes to PCA the program asks me if I want to normalize the data or not, but I am not sure about that because I have already calculated the percentage - is normalize different from calculating the percentage? Moreover, below the normalize button it asks me to show only:... and I have to choose a number between 0 and 100 but I don’t really know what it is.

Could you help me understand what I should do? Thank you in advance